# How to have two different <span> activate if hovering over only one?

Tags: html, css

Normally, both .labout spans are white and both .pabout spans are yellow. When hovering over I would the whole phrase to be black. i.e. LEARN ABOUT FULL SERVICE be black when any part of the button is hovered over, not an individual span.

```
<div id="inner">
    <a style="color:white" href="full-service/overview/" class="fs-button">
        <span class="labout">LEARN ABOUT</span>
        <span class="pabout"> FULL SERVICE</span>
    </a>                    
    <a style="color:white; vertical-align:middle;" href="diy/overview/" class="diy-button">
        <span class="labout">LEARN ABOUT</span>
        <span class="pabout">  DO IT YOURSELF</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

However, with the css I have, only the individual span you hover over turns black and the rest of the phrase does not. Here is my css:

```
a.fs-button {
    display: inline;
    background: #28353e;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 245px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'asenine';
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

a span.pabout {
    color: #f6ec02;
}

.home-buttons a span.labout:hover {
    color: black;
}   

.home-buttons a span.pabout:hover {
    color: black;
}   

.home-buttons a.fs-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500; 
    background: #f7ed04; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #f7ed04 0%, #eda704 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#f7ed04), color-stop(100%,#eda704)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #f7ed04 0%,#eda704 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #f7ed04 0%,#eda704 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #f7ed04 0%,#eda704 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #f7ed04 0%,#eda704 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7ed04', endColorstr='#eda704',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You just have the hover on the wrong selector.  You want to color depending on whether the `a` is hovered, not whether an individual span is hovered.

```
a:hover .pabout, a:hover .labout { color: black; }
```

SIDENOTE: You have style in the `style` attribute and then overwrite it in the selector `.home-buttons a.fs-button:hover`.  Your selector will not overwrite a `style` attribute.  Try not to mix css classes and inline style.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `:hover` on the parent `a`, not the spans themselves:

```
.home-buttons a.fs-button:hover span.labout,
.home-buttons a.fs-button:hover span.pabout {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
.fs-button:hover .labout,
.fs-button:hover .pabout{ color:#000 }
```